# Trying to query for cell above contains

Tags: google-sheets

I have a column of data that contains names, and the name always appears above a cell which contains parentheses. I'm able to run a query that shows those cells

=query(A:A,"Select * where A contains '('",)

but it's the cells directly preceding them that I need. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
=index(hlookup("z",{"z";A:A},filter(row(A:A),regexmatch(A:A,"\(")),0))
```

[image]

You can replace the two occurrences of `z` with whatever you want.

The formula is self-explanatory if you are familiar with [HLOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093375?hl=en) and arrays.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=QUERY(A:A; "skipping 2")
```

or:

```
=QUERY(A:A; "where not A contains '('")
```